# Error during run Android Google Maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Ago, I used the google map android v1, i update to v2, I can not display the map. and received force close error. please help me!

My code:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="lvs.android.map"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>

<permission
        android:name="lvs.android.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="lvs.android.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
</application>
```

LOGCAT

```
  12-11 11:21:26.664: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4242)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    at lvs.android.map.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your `MyActivity` code also .

Comment: Have you included Playservices lib?

Comment: If you are running the application on emulator, have you made the Target `Google API` instead of `Android`.?

Comment: I add lib jar play service. and i running the application on galaxy Tab.

Comment: I use Intellij for programming. I don't know add project lib play service to my project. i used file .jar.

Comment: How did you integrate the Google Play Services library? Are you using gradle/Android Studio? That error means a style if not found by the map because the library is wrongly integrated.

Answer (score 1):

Google play service revision 13 you should have to add one more meta tag in your manifest.xml.Insert it inside your application tag.So there will be two meta tags in your application tag.If you still need any help.Just follow this [link](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable`"Add this in your manifest file :

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your application tag

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

your application should look like this

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="removed" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: I didn't notice your answer and you were seconds away from me. I am not gonna delete it so deal with it. be more supportive rather than stingy.